# What is this tiny pink flower in lawn?

Tags: identification, flowering, wildflowers

What is this tiny pink flower? Found in my mother's lawn in Norfolk, Virginia. It's so small, but they're showing up randomly here and there. Stalk appears to be greener at the top near the bloom and reddish pink below that all the way into the ground. Cute little booger. I do not wish to get rid of them, but they'll most likely end up being mowed down; not sure if it's worth transplanting them yet, as they're so tiny  and delicate looking. You even see the little buds in the pic, looking like a deeper pink almost purple.

[image: tiny pink flower]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term 'wood violet' is somewhat vague - this is actually one of the Oxalis varieties, so not a Viola at all; it's probably Oxalis latifolia, maybe Oxalis violacaea, often commonly known as wood sorrel (in the UK anyway). The easily identified foliage is not actually visible in the photograph with your question. Image of Oxalis latifolia here, but it's a Spanish site http://botanicmontserrat.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/aleluya.html.

Oxalis have a collection of little brown bulbils at the base of the stems, usually underground, and often a larger, opaque white oval shaped bulb beneath - in order to get rid of it, or transplant it to a more suitable spot, you must ensure you get all parts of the plant out. It spreads widely, and probably isn't something you want taking over your lawn, but, though it is invasive, it's a pretty plant and will grow in shady areas. A better option though, if you want to grow it in the border in a semi shaded spot, is Oxalis debilis, which is similar but has larger flowers.

Comment: Great @Bamboo ! I looked up some if the pics and this appears to be a perfect match. Some other bunches were found with the clover like leaves so this seems right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a wood violet. Lots of variations of purple, pinks and blues.[wood violet](https://images.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=AwrTcePkWthZ0mEAIBknnIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTByNWU4cGh1BGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzYw--?p=Wood%20Violet&fr=yhs-mozilla-002&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002)

Comment: @Christy B.  Little wild flowers are nice but a lawn is a mono culture...normally.  If you raise your mower deck so that you cut no lower than 3 inches...you'll probably not touch this cutie.  I see a bit much un decomposed debris in your lawn.  Please bag your clippings, your mower should suck up this debris.  Do not leave clippings.  Another story for later.  Your mower blades need sharpening.  See the ragged ends of the grass blades? Not a good thing.  I would take a leaf rake and rake the grass hard before mowing.  Keep the deck on high.  Move slowly over the lawn.  Have you fertilized?

Comment: Lawn service takes care of it in this community: you take care of the back yard, they take care of the front, but Ill mention it to her-wether or not they do it is something different. I'll ask about fertilizer

Comment: 'Lawn Service' I know very well.  Those people rarely employ anyone who knows anything and have a hard time getting their employees licensed for pesticide, understanding 2 stroke engines much less caring about life and what the client expects.  They know nothing.  Clients rarely know enough to question their lawn service.  That means they get away doing a service they have no business doing.  I'll help you test your service.  I had many seminars just for maintenance laborers...and foremen.  To help them get their pesticide license.  Ask whether they have a license any license.

Comment: I read your profile yesterday @stormy ;very impressive. You have alot to teach me and the community!

Comment: All of us have such diverse backgrounds!  We work best as a team.  My priority is my own information, not allowing what I know to go stagnant.  I need to learn, get feedback, I am selfish firstest.  I love finding gardener wannabees and encouraging them to continue learning and working at becoming a gardener.  Well, we are all a work in progress and I hope their is no end point...none of us should or could know everything!  Love hanging with others that know the same language!  Being questioned...

Comment: ..shoot 'THERE' not 'Their'...I gotta edit a bit more slowly.